# "Товарищ" — женский род

Tags: грамотная-речь

В литературе иногда попадается слово "товарка". Но я не знаю, считается ли оно устаревшим и вообще есть ли в русском языке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хороший вопрос.
Слово это в русском языке есть. Оно фиксируется (как разговорное) как современными словарями, так и достаточно давними (есть у Ушакова). В литературе фиксируется с 70-х годов XIX века.

Но тут одна тонкость. Слово "товарищ" в современном языке имеет несколько значений. "Товарка" соответствует только одному из них: друг, приятель.
Значения "коллега по работе", "помощник" и т.д. а также форма обращения (в армии) женской формы не имеют и не имели.

Интересно, что в болгарском, где в "годы социализма" обращение "товарищ" (другар) также использовалось как общеупотребительное, его женская форма (другарка) было нормативным по отношению к женщине.

Comment: В болгарском языке никогда небыло слово "товарищ", а также и "товарка". У нас были другие слова: "другар" и "другарка"

Comment: @user195340  *В болгарском языке никогда небыло слово "товарищ",* - я согласен, формулировка была крайне неудачная. Я поправил текст, спасибо.